# how to make the app running well

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

i have some UIViews,and there are some buttons on the first UIView,the click function of them likes this

```
-(IBAction)securityClicked:(id)sender
{ 

SwitchViewController* switchViewController = (SwitchViewController*)[wangfan_chevyAppDelegate App].viewController;
[switchViewController.wtccviewcontroller.scrollView1 setContentOffset:CGPointMake(
                            1024*0, 0) animated:false];
[[testAppDelegate App] pushViewFromRight:switchViewController.wtccviewcontroller
                                            over:self];

}
```

and the wtccviewcontroller.m file's code is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];    

UIViewController* controller = nil;

controller = [[Wtcc1ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Wtcc1ViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*0, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];   
//[controller release];

controller = [[Wtcc2ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Wtcc2ViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*1, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];   
//[controller release];

controller = [[Wtcc3ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Wtcc3ViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*2, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];   
//[controller release];

controller = [[Wtcc4ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Wtcc4ViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*3, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];   
//[controller release];

controller = [[SecurityViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecurityViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*4, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];   
//[controller release];

controller = [[Security2ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Security2ViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*5, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];   
//[controller release];

controller = [[Onstar1ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Onstar1ViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*6, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];   
//[controller release];

controller = [[Movie1ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Movie1ViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*7, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];   
//[controller release];

controller = [[CarownerViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CarownerView" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*8, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];   
//[controller release];

controller = [[Co01ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Co01ViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*9, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];

controller = [[Co02ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Co02ViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*10, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];

controller = [[Co03ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Co03ViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*11, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];

controller = [[Co04ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Co04ViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*12, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];

controller = [[Co05ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Co05ViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*13, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];

controller = [[Co06ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Co06ViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*14, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];

controller = [[Co07ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Co07ViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*15, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];

controller = [[ConfigViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ConfigViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*16, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];

    [scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024*17,768)];
   }
```

because there are a lot of controllers,so when i click the button on the first view,it will be loaded so long,even quit the app,so how should i do for make it running well?

Comment: What do you mean by "well?"  High-performing?  Easily maintainable?  Friendly to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you call [alloc] you create an object (for each controller) then you must release it. You can do this after adding the subview since this retains it.

I see you commented out the [controller release] some times and then totally forgot about it.

Also you're adding a lot of controllers here. You could add the first in viewDidLoad and load lazily each other controller only when clicked.

Comment: The view will only retain the added view, not the view controller that holds the view!

Comment: Oops, that's true! My comment would only be correct is he was pushing a viewcontroller on the stack. Anyway I think kubi's comment above sums up the problems better.

Answer (score 2):

At least three major issues with your code:

1. You are leaking objects like crazy. You are allocating multiple view controllers but never releasing them. In fact, since you are reassigning the `controller` variable, you are losing a reference to those objects so that you can never release them.
2. Do not use multiple `UIViewController` objects to control parts of a single view. The view controller is designed and intended to be used full-screen (or as part of a `UINavigationController`, `UITabBarController`, etc). You should be using individual `UIView` objects and controlling them from a central controller object and/or using your own lightweight view controllers.
3. Your final view size is something like 8192x768; that is massive. At the very least you can use a `UITableViewController` to intelligently cache parts of your view. This screen should probably be broken apart into smaller views, though.